# Use jwilder-nginx-proxy without mounting docker socket

Tags: docker, security, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I'm trying to follow guidelines of [docker-bench-security](https://github.com/docker/docker-bench-security). I'm trying to comply with this rules : `Ensure the Docker socket is not mounted inside any containers`.

I've read that `jwilder-nginx-proxy` does not need docker socket to me mounted if it can access it through HTTPS.

I think my docker installation is working, I can communicate with the docker API from my host :

```
curl https://127.0.0.1:2376/version --cert /home/ubuntu/.docker/cert.pem   --key /home/ubuntu/.docker/key.pem   --cacert /home/ubuntu/.docker/ca.pem
{"Platform":{"Name":"Docker Engine - Community"},"Components":...}
```

But I can't access it from nginx jwilder :

```
******@******:~/docker/proxy$ docker exec -ti nginx bash
root@c4740dcc00d9:/app# curl https://127.0.0.1:2376/version --cert /home/ubuntu/.docker/cert.pem   --key /home/ubuntu/.docker/key.pem   --cacert /home/ubuntu/.docker/ca.pem
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 2376: Connection refused
root@c4740dcc00d9:/app#  curl https://172.17.0.1:2376/version --cert /home/ubuntu/.docker/cert.pem   --key /home/ubuntu/.docker/key.pem   --cacert /home/ubuntu/.docker/ca.pem -m 5
curl: (28) Connection timed out after 5000 milliseconds
```

Here's my `docker-compose.yml` :

```
nginx:
  container_name: nginx
  image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
  ports:
    - 80:80
    - 443:443
  environment:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://127.0.0.1:2376
    DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY:
    DOCKER_CERT_PATH:
  volumes:
    - ./certs:${DOCKER_CERT_PATH}
```

And the daemon.json file :

```
{
        "icc": false,
        "userns-remap": "default",
        "log-driver": "local",
        "live-restore": true,
        "tls": true,
        "tlsverify": true,
        "tlscacert": "/etc/docker/ssl/ca.pem",
        "tlscert": "/etc/docker/ssl/daemon-cert.pem",
        "tlskey": "/etc/docker/ssl/daemon-key.pem",
        "hosts": ["unix:///var/run/docker.sock", "tcp://127.0.0.1:2376"],
        "default-ulimit": "nofile=50:100",
        "userland-proxy": false
}
```

I don't know how to reach docker API through jwilder. Is there something to add on the docker-compose file ? or in the docker configuration ? which address should i use to reach it from the containers ?

Thank in advance to point me in the right direction!